Enterprise Application Distribution Certificates and "iOS Distribution Managed"
I'm at a loss regarding the current way Apple has recently changed Enterprise Application distribution. Normally I would expect to find two distribution certificates, my current one which has only a few months left, and a previous used one that's since expired, which I could revoke and create an updated distribution cert with 3 years expiry. Instead, I see my current enterprise cert, the teams personal dev certs and a couple of distribution certs marked "iOS Distribution Managed", owned by a developer who no longer works with the team. I see no way to create a new distribution certificate that can be downloaded to enable me to create an app build whose lifetime will overlap with builds currently distributed. Calling Apple Developer Support, they suggest that I wait until my current distribution cert dies then push out new apps. That would likely leave the field without working apps for several days.
Any suggestions?

You can update certificates through mdm push technology, ota distribution, or application internal update mechanism.
